# Stale directory contents and "net use"

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, server-message-block, net-use

I have two Windows Server 2008 SP2 machines. Occasionally I see that when I open a file share with `net use`, the contents are stale.  The scenario is:

1. `net use Z: \\192.168.0.100\c$`
2. Add a file to a directory on the C: drive on C:'s host machine
3. I don't see the file on the networked machines Z: drive.

It eventually appears but I can't figure out how to speed up this process when it occurs.  Simply refreshing the directory does not help. Doing a "net use /d Z:" and re-adding it doesn't work either.

Any ideas what is causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: It might help to provide details on OS/ServicePack of the client and server machines.

Comment: How long is it before it eventually appears?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the properties of the share. Make sure that under `Caching` you have selected `No files or programs from the shared folder are available offline`